# Trouble with class prototyping in C++

Tags: c++, class, object, prototype

Basically my code has 2 classes:

```
class teacher { 
    //has object of class course
};
class course { 
    //has object of class teacher
};
```

This wasn't working, as teacher was not able to access class course because it is written after class teacher. So then I tried creating class prototypes.

```
class teacher;
class course;
.....
class teacher {
    //object of class course
};
class course {
    //object of class teacher
};
```

Still doesn't work. And yes i do need these classes to hold each others objects. Pleasee tell me this can work the way I want it too, and I don't have to change my code. Would really appreciate some help. Thank you.

Comment: You can't have `teacher` have a `course` member and `course` have a `teacher` member as each would need to contain an infinite number of itself.

Comment: Pointers might solve this, but perhaps you should reveal some more detail of your problem.

Comment: The relation between `teacher` and `course` you are trying to express is unclear, and it's unclear why forward declaration didn't work for you. Please share a [MCVE] that better illustrates the problem.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Dammit, so I need to change my logic :(. Basically i want an array of courses in teacher class and an array of teachers in courses class.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux one teacher can teach multiple courses, and one course can have multiple teachers teaching it

Comment: @Abdullahnawazkhan Logically, you would need a container of `teacher` and a separate container of `course`. A `teacher` doesn't "own" the courses and a `course` doesn't "own" it's teacher. Edit : Perhaps you are coming from a background where most objects are references. In c++ each instance of `teacher` is it's own unique `teacher`. In c++ you use references and pointers to refer to common instances.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux hmm alright thanks. I'll do some research on containers.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I wanted each teacher to have a dynamic Array consisting of 
course objects. And i wanted each course to have a dynamic array consisting of teacher objects.

Comment: @Abdullahnawazkhan With that architecture, if `teacher A` has a `course B` it's not possible for `course B`'s teachers to include `teacher A`. They would be entirely different `teacher`s.

Comment: Perhaps you can have a `teacher` contain an array of `course` ids and a `course` hold an array of `teacher` ids?

Comment: @Galik yeah i was thinking of just storing teacher and courses names rather than complete object.

Comment: @Galik yeah totally gonna do this. Assignment is due tomorrow. Don't have time for researching more lol. I'll do some more research later on for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should view this as a database issue.
Let's have another table containing teachers and courses:

```
class Teacher_Course
{
  Teacher t;
  Course c;
}
```

The table could be represented as:

```
std::vector<Teacher_Course> tc_table;
```

The picture would be:

```
+---------+----------+  
| Teacher | Course   |  
+---------+----------+  
| Schults | Math 1   |  
+---------+----------+  
| Schults | Calculus |  
+---------+----------+  
| Jonez   | History1 |
+---------+----------+
```

This schema allows your `Teacher` and `Course` classes to be independent.  The *relationship* is modeled by the `Teacher_Course` class.

Thus eliminating any circular dependencies between `Teacher` and `Course`.

*Note:  to be more database friendly, you may want to have record IDs and research foreign keys*

Answer (score 1):

Code that works for what you probably want to do:

teacher.h

```
#include <vector>
using std::vector;
class Course;

class Teacher
{
vector<Course*> courses;
...
};
```

course.h

```
#include <vector>
using std::vector;
class Teacher;

class Course
{
vector<Teachers*> teachers;
...
};
```

Note that in the source files, you will want to include both header files, as right now, `Teacher` does not know the functionality of `Course` vice versa.

I did this with raw pointers to make it easier for you to understand, but you should switch to some sort of smart pointers at some point (in this case probably `weak_ptr`).

Btw, usually, one writes class names with major first letters.

Comment: Capitalization is entirely a matter of style and preference. It's not correct to hold one style or preference as the right one. Notably, the standard library doesn't have any capital letters in it's type names and opting to follow it's example is a fine choice if you want to keep things uniform.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Well, I wrote *usually*. STL doesn't, but about everything other major project, library etc does. Most projects he will ever join will.

Comment: Again, that's subjective to your experiences. It's not because it's true *in your experiences* that's true in general. The generic advice on this topic is to follow whatever style guide or style is already in use by the project, team, organization, etc.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Kay, now I'm curious. Do you have different experiences here, for bigger projects that is? If not, then my answer is this: a style that almost anyone uses is a style you should make your routine. I don't care if it is arbitrary and could be done a different way.

Comment: I already mentioned a "big project" that uses lower case type names : the standard library. But it doesn't matter which project uses which convention. Holding one convention above others because it's more popular is dangerously close to cargo-cult behavior. Conventions have a reason for the stylistic decisions they make. It's more useful to understand the compromises and trade-offs of one choice over the others than it is to memorize a single style and applying blindly. That is why advice regarding stylistic rules of thumb are harmful, they lead to cargo-cult and thoughtless behavior.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux But the answer didn't say it was the _the_ right one. It says "usually", which is a very reasonable point - if only because it makes SO's syntax highlighting work correctly.

Comment: @MaxLanghof That's a good point. I hadn't noticed the syntax highlighting thing. That's a fine reason for favoring capitalized class names when posting on Stack Overflow. Edit : Regarding the "usually", the sentence may still sound authoritative for many readers who would take it as a rule of thumb to be applied. If they *are* working a big project, the style will be apparent. If they aren't, they should use the style that best suites the situation.